# How to postback to same view page in mvc4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Here is the code that I have so far. . .

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}


[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var result = "cobn";

    return View("Index", result);
}
```

I am unable to return to same page after post.
How to return to same view?

Comment: Can you show `Index` view code?

Comment: try `return RedirectToAction`